# issue while trying to insert one table into another one

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a mysql table of 1.5 million record in a temproary table that I want to insert it into the main table with an inner join.

My code works but it stops at 103,613 records. IT does not keep going. Why would it stops? why it is not going all the way to the end?

This is my current code

```
INSERT INTO phone_calls(next_attempt, created_on, modified_on, status, call_subject,
account_number, call_code, last_attempt_on, total_attempts, account_id

,team_id
,campaign_id
,call_code_id
,result_code
,result_code_id
,time_zone_id
,trigger_on
,first_attempt_on
,first_attempt_by
,last_attempt_by
,modified_by
,client_id
,last_call_id
,call_notes
,owner_id
,industry_id
)


SELECT 
CASE WHEN next_attempt IS NULL OR next_attempt = '' THEN STR_TO_DATE(replace(t.next_attempt,'/',','),'%m,%d,%Y %T') END as next_attempt,
CASE WHEN t.created_on IS NULL OR t.created_on = '' THEN '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ELSE STR_TO_DATE(replace(t.created_on,'/',','),'%m,%d,%Y %T') END as created_on,
CASE WHEN t.modified_on IS NULL OR t.modified_on = '' THEN '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ELSE STR_TO_DATE(replace(t.modified_on,'/',','),'%m,%d,%Y %T') END AS modified_on,
CONVERT( CASE WHEN t.status IS NULL OR t.status = '' THEN 0 ELSE t.status END,  UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS status,
LEFT(IFNULL(t.call_subject, ''), 100),
t.account_number,
CONVERT( CASE WHEN t.callcode IS NULL OR t.callcode = '' THEN 0 ELSE t.callcode END , UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS callcode, STR_TO_DATE(replace(t.last_attempt_on,'/',','),'%m,%d,%Y %T') as last_attempt_on,
CONVERT( CASE WHEN t.New_Attempts IS NULL OR t.New_Attempts = '' THEN 0 ELSE t.New_Attempts END ,  UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS New_Attempts,
a.account_id
,0
,0
,0
,0
,0
,0
, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
,1
,1
,1
,1
,0
,'IMPORTED FROM CRM'
,1
,1
FROM tmp_table_for_rdi_cms AS t
INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.account_number = t.account_number LIMIT 9999999999;
these 2 fields are indexed so it runs fast
a.account_number
t.account_number
```

Now, I know i am inserting no value for some fields that has a type if unsigned integer but that is okay as i will be updating this at later time.

How can i execute this INSERT INTO query without losing any record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "doesnt have a default value" problem is that the source table has nulls for columns on the new table that are defined S NOT NULL *and* which are not defined with a default value.

You have three choices to fix this:

1. Define the target columns as null able (leave out the NOT NULL)
2. Define the target columns with a default value, ie `NOT NULL DEFAULT 'some value'`
3. Provide a value if the column is null, ie `SELECT ifnull(source_column, 'some value)`

The *Truncated incorrect INTEGER value*  problems and you are selecting from a char value and putting it in an int column, but some vyes are blank, so you need to handle that:

```
select if(source_column = '', 0, source_column)
```

The *Data truncated for column* problem is there because the source value is larger/longer than the target column can accommodate. To fix, define your target column to be larger (bigint instead of int) or longer (eg text or varchar(80) instead of varchar(20))